# Consecutive random draws from a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I am studying consecutive independent events that last more or less 11 hours. The duration of the event follows a Normal distribution ($\mu_0 = 11$, $\sigma_0 = 1.1$). When an event finishes, a new one starts immediately, forming a chain of events. At $t=0min$, all chains of events (thousands of them) are perfectly synchronized, but of course they de-synchronize slowly.

Playing with the data, I realized that the end time of an event follows a Normal distribution too ($\mu = \mu_0n$, $\sigma = \sigma_0\sqrt{n}$ with $n$ the generation of the event in its chain).

I am able to reproduce this observation numerically using R:

```
s0  <- 1.1 # Standard deviation
l0  <- 11  # Average duration of events (in hours)
num <- 5   # Number of generations to compute

# Initial length (t) of all chain of events is zero
t  <- rep(0, 10000)
for (i in seq(num)) {
  # Add the result of random draws to the time length of each chain of events
  t  <- rnorm(length(t), mean = l0 + t, sd = s0)

  # Display an histogram of the end time of each chain of events
  hist(t, main = paste0("Histogram of generation #", i), freq = F)

  # Draw the theoretical end time
  xs <- seq(min(t), max(t), 0.05)
  lines(xs, dnorm(xs, i*l0, sqrt(i)*s0), col = 'red')
}
```

But I cannot figure out a proof for that. I am not even sure *what* is happening mathematically when the R script is running.

Any help would be very much appreciated to point me in the right direction.

Comment: As you have observed, the sum of independent normal variables is again normal.  See, e.g., [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17800/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-sum-of-independent-normal-variables).

Comment: Thank you @lulu – I somehow missed this very simple point!